# Почему у разных телефонов разный путь к файлу?

Tags: java, android

столкнулс с проблемой того, что мне надо захватывать файл и получать путь к нему с помощью getData(). При тесте на телефоне с API 29, я получил такой путь:
"file path: content://media/external/file/2796"
Является ли это нормой? И если да, то как мне передать этот путь в переменную File?

Comment: Да, для Андроида это норма и про файлы во внешней памяти можете уже не вспоминать - в следующей версии даже с разрешения пользователя они не будут доступны простым смертным приложениям. То, что вы видите, называется content-uri и по нему можно получить данные посредством класса [`ContentResolver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver). Для медиа файлов есть ещё `MediaStore`, в частности для изображений [`MediaStore.Images.Media`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это норма. Скорее всего такой `Uri` предоставляет `FileProvider` какого-то приложения, которое вы используете для выбора файла. Создатели Android постепенно вводят ограничения на чтение файловой системы с помощью класса File, поэтому приходится использовать `Uri` для чтения и записи файлов. Для этого можно создать `InputStream` (для чтения) или `OutputStream` (для записи), используя `ContentResolver` (его можно получить у `Context`):

```
getContentResolver().openInputStream(intent.getData())

getContentResolver().openOutputStream(intent.getData())
```

Comment: Я использовал это:
public static String getRealPathFromUri(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }